# Как оптимизировать программу? python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, оптимизация, python-3.6

```
i = 0
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
x, y = map(int, input().split())
x = a - x
y = b - y

if x == 0:
    pass
elif (x+abs(x)) > 0:
    i += x
else:
    pass

if y == 0:
    pass
elif (y+abs(y)) > 0:
    i += y
else:
    pass
x = abs(x)+abs(y)
x = x - c
print(abs(x))
```

Comment: Объясните в вопросе что должен делать данный код

Comment: Все условия в результате которых вызывается “pass” можно убрать и заменить “elif” на “if”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, например,

```
if y == 0:
    pass
elif (y+abs(y)) > 0:
    i += y
else:
    pass
```

Итак, что-то выполняется, если `y` не равно 0 и `y+abs(y) > 0`. Если `y` равно 0, это последнее условие не выполнено. Если `y<0` - тоже. Так что весь блок заменяется

```
if y > 0: i += y
```

То же самое верно и для аналогичного блока `x`.

А вообще, даже это можно выбросить, потому что `i` никакой роли в вычислениях не играет :) Так что после получения переменными значений можно просто писать

```
print(abs(abs(x-a)+abs(y-b)-c))
```

*"По-моему так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.